# Jackson: Serializing Map<Object, BigDecimal> yields undesired object reference

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Suppose I am trying to serialize the following with Jackson:

```
public class Investment implements Serializable{
   private String shortName;
   private MutualFund mutualFund;

   public String getShortName() {
       return shortName;
   }

   public void setShortName(String shortName) {
       this.shortName = shortName;
   }

   public MutualFund getMutualFund() {
      return mutualFund;
   }

   public void setMutualFund(MutualFund mutualFund) {
      this.mutualFund = mutualFund;
   }
}
```

That in turn refers to:

```
public class MutualFund implements Serializable{
   private BigDecimal expenseRatio;
   private Map<Investment, BigDecimal> underlyingInvestments;

   public BigDecimal getExpenseRatio() {
      return BigDecimalHelper.guard(expenseRatio);
   }

   public void setExpenseRatio(BigDecimal expenseRatio) {
      this.expenseRatio = expenseRatio;
   }

   public Map<Investment, BigDecimal> getUnderlyingInvestments() {
      return underlyingInvestments;
   }

   public void setUnderlyingInvestments(Map<Investment, BigDecimal> 
      underlyingFunds) {
      this.underlyingInvestments = underlyingFunds;
   }
}
```

When I try to serialize this with Jackson, everything else is fine except that I end up with an Investment object reference instead of the string with attributes like I was expecting:

```
"underlyingInvestments":{"com.financial.detail.Investment@5d465e4b":1}}
```

I've tried to fashion some custom serializers, but without success as I always get an object reference for the *nested* Investment(s). So, I have a two part question:

1. Can this problem be addressed simply with Jackson annotations?
2. If I have to build a custom serializer, could someone kindly point me in the right direction on how to best
   approach this issue given the nested nature of this (e.g. an Investment could contain a Mutual Fund, which in turn has an Investment with a Mutual Fund...)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the object `Investment` as keys of a Map, so the question here is, what keys do you expect the json to have? Json keys cand only be strings so the mapper is executing the `toString()` method of the `Investment` class. If you know what that key should be, then you can implement the method, like this:

```java
public class Investment implements Serializable {
        private String shortName;
        private MutualFund mutualFund;

        // ...

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return shortName;
        }
    }
```

This will create a json object like this:

```json
{
    "expenseRatio": 1,
    "underlyingInvestments": {
        "shortName": 10
    }
}
```

Also, as @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic suggested, another option is to use `@JsonValue` to indicate which method to use when serializing, like this:

```java
public class Investment implements Serializable{
   private String shortName;
   private MutualFund mutualFund;

   @JsonValue
   public String getShortName() {
       return shortName;
   }

   // ...
}
```

Comment: Much better to use `@JsonValue`.

Comment: Good point @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-, I added that too. Thanks